# How to print out certain elements based on location?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a javascript function that gets a users current position, and another one that generates bikes in random locations between some specific coordinates.

I would like to print out the nearest 5 in the console log (or for example all bikes that are less than 0.05 long and lat away. I am not sure where to begin, does anyone have an idea?

Here is my javascript code

The for each loop in the bottom is how I tried to do it, but I'm not sure how to access the position const.

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
  //Location is supported by the browser
  const locationElement = document.getElementById("location")
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position)
    locationElement.innerText = `${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`
  })
}
  
  class Bike{
    constructor(name, location){
      this.name = name;
      this.location = location;
    }

  }
  
  class Location {
    constructor(lat, lon) {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lon = lon
    }
  }

  const bikes = [];

  for(let i= 1; i<30; i++) {
    const name = `CityBike${i}`
    const location = new Location(Math.random()/10 + 55.5, Math.random()/10 + 12.5)
    
    const bike = new Bike(name, location)
    
    bikes.push(bike)
  }
  
  bikes.forEach((bike) => {
    
    if((bike.location - position) < 0.1) {
      console.log(bike)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As getting a location is an async operation, you need to check if the locations are within the range or not, inside the getCurrentPosition's callback method. Also, I think it'd be better to use current location as circle's center coordinates, choose a radius based on how farther you want to go, make a circle and check if the other bike's locations are inside the circle or not.
Right now I have just changed to code to make it work for the comparison of longitutde and latitude.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      //Location is supported by the browser
      //const locationElement = document.getElementById("location")
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(`${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`);
        const myLocation = new Location(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitutde);
        bikes.forEach((bike) => {
    
          if ((myLocation.lat - bike.location.lat) < 0.1 && (myLocation.lon - bike.location.lon) < 0.1) {
            console.log(bike);
          }
        })
        //locationElement.innerText = `${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}`
      })
    }
    
    class Bike {
      constructor(name, location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
      }
    
    }
    var bikes = [];
    class Location {
      constructor(lat, lon) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon
      }
    }
    
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      const name = `CityBike${i}`
      const location = new Location(Math.random() / 10 + 55.5, Math.random() / 10 + 12.5)
      console.log(location);
      const bike = new Bike(name, location)
    
      bikes.push(bike)
    }
```